# Avoiding major/minor version conflicts with Java/Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven

Is it a good idea to publish a Maven project using this kind of scheme:

```
<groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
<artifactId>async.1</artifactId>

<groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
<artifactId>async.2</artifactId>

<groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
<artifactId>async.3</artifactId>
```

where these represent *major* releases of the projects? Would this not be an effective way to create a different namespace so that different dependencies in the tree could depend on different versions of this library? Does anyone do this or is this a bad practice?

I was even thinking about namespacing them by minor version too:

```
<groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
<artifactId>async.1.1</artifactId>

<groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
<artifactId>async.1.2</artifactId>

<groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
<artifactId>async.1.3</artifactId>
```

**Update**, supposedly this is what Apache Commons did between version 3 and 4, here are two different imports:

*version 3:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

*version 4:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

*So my question is - to have a different package name or namespace, is it sufficient to use a different **artifactId** or do we also need a different **groupId**?*

Comment: Simple answer to this: No. Use the version tag instead which is exactly intended and use semantical versioning...

Comment: My understanding is that the version tag does *not* actually allow two different versions of the "same" dependency in a single application?

Comment: It is not allowed it not cause it does not make sense cause you can't have duplicate classes on the classpath nor things like Java modules does not work. And having the need to have different versions of the same artifact you a real problem..and the question: Why would you need such thing?

Comment: It's not my code that needs different versions (although that does happen on rare occasion) - instead,  some dependency I have depends on a different version than I do. This is called dependency hell, and it can be avoided, Java doesn't avoid it very well.

Comment: If a single artifact needs different versions there is general problem in that...You need to make a decision. Furthermore If your own code uses a different version than you need to make the decision to use the older/newer one which is used indirectly via that dependency. ? Maybe you can overrule the used dependency and the code will work but that is not guaranteed which can only being proofed by tests....

Comment: If your pom.xml has a version tag that differs slightly from the version tag of another dependency, Maven will try to find a way to use some version that satisfies both, but it's not ideal.  NPM does a better job at allowing more than one version of a dep in a dependency tree. See @JF Meier's answer

Comment: The issue has been made in the beginning by using a wrong groupId which is not `org.apache.commons`..This has been changed with the version 4. But usually you should never change groupId/artifactId just because you want to change the version (It does not matter if major or minor version etc.) ....

Comment: *"to have a different package name or namespace, is it sufficient to use a different artifactId or do we also need a different groupId?"* It is sufficient to use a different artifactId. There is no *functional* differences between change one or both, it's just used for organizational purposes. See [Guide to naming conventions on groupId, artifactId, and version](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html), which might help you determine whether you should change both.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is only a different *namespace* if the **package** name of the classes are also different.

Since they are likely not, you're just setting yourself up for more trouble, since you can now add more than one version of the classes. Given that the classpath order is usually unordered (e.g. in a webapp), it'll be arbitrary which one you'll actually see at compile-time and/or runtime, causing unpredictable behavior.

Now, if you also rename the packages, like what [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) did between version 3.x and 4.x, then you should rename the maven group/artifact too, so you can have both on the classpath.

Otherwise you should instead try to make the code backwards compatible, so a newer version of the library can be used without causing issues.

Comment: Can you please show actual examples of groupId/artifactId of what to do vs. what not to do? thanks. If I follow what you are saying, I could do this `com.oresoftware.async1.1.async`?  Not sure if numbers/dots are allowed there or not.

Comment: @AlexanderMills You're asking about *releases* of your library. "Release" is another word for "version", so you should only change the `<version>` value for new *releases* of the library. Now if you change all the Java package names, then it is not really the same library any more, and the `<groupId>` and/or `<artifactId>` value should be changed.

Comment: Well you know what I am trying to do - I am trying to use a different package namespace so that if a project wants to use two different versions of a library it could.  so I would have something like `import com.oresoftware.async1.Async` and in another file I would have something like `import com.oresoftware.async2.Async`, right? but how do I set that up, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Did you even read my answer? Let me summarize: *If you rename the packages, you should rename the maven group/artifact.* How you rename them is entirely up to you. --- Problem is that your question only asked about rename the group/artifact without in mentioning the Java package names. If your question had been clearer, you would have gotten a clearer answer.

Comment: Bro, you know what I am trying to do (right?). If there is a way to do what I want to do, please show me how. I don't know how, your answer is not good enough, to be frank. The question could have been a little clearer, but I think it's clear enough and too late to change it.

Comment: One thing that would help me and others - if there is a way to link to the pom.xml files of the two different Apache-Commons versions.

Comment: "Now, if you also rename the packages, like what Apache Commons Collections" can you please show how the packages were renamed?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I don't know what you're *trying* to do, other than just naming it differently, because that's all you *question* says. As such, my answer explains why *only* changing the artifactId is a bad thing, and that you should change it only *in concert* with changing the Java package name. My answer is perhaps not good enough because your question isn't good, so perhaps you should **edit the question and clarify it**.

Comment: @AlexanderMills I provided you a link to Apache Commons Collections so you could go take a look for yourself. Click the "Javadoc 3.2.2" link on that page, and any of the "Javadoc 4" links, to see the package names. You could also read the "Release Notes 4.0" which describes the renames and why they were done.

Comment: Are you able to click on "package"? I cannot. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/index.html

Comment: @AlexanderMills Why would I want to do that? All the package names are listed right there on that page. Twice, actually.

Comment: Ok I just updated the OP with what I kind of wanted you to include earlier - so are you saying that the groupId needs to be different or just the artifactId needs to be different? that is what remains unclear to me.

Comment: Ok I was confused, the package name can only be changed by the folder structure in your maven project - so I suppose that the groupId/artifact is just a pointer to the folder structure (package) that you expect. I don't see why they shouldn't have to match in that case, seems like a design flaw.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Maybe you should read [Guide to naming conventions on groupId, artifactId, and version](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html). Keep in mind that you should never have two different jar files (ignoring version) that have the same fully qualifier class in it, since adding both to the classpath would then cause issues. Not adding two *versions* of a jar file is obviously not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this, as Andreas talked about in the other answer. But it is rarely done.

I thought about concepts like these myself, and I guess the main reason is that upgrading from version n to n+1 becomes much harder. You need to go through all the code and replace the imports. Furthermore, if you use objects from your library in interfaces, you bind your method parameters to a specific version of the library (through the imports) and make interoperability harder.

Often, upgrading from n to n+1 does not mean that everything breaks, but maybe just a little bit, so going through all the code may be harder than accepting the problems of the usual version scheme.

Comment: That's true, but I think a simple pattern replacer would do for all your files. But I otherwise agree, so maybe only for major versions would we bump the number up.

Comment: I updated the OP, if you can answer the question at the bottom of the OP I think you would help people beyond just myself.

Comment: If two artifacts have different groupId and/or different artifactId, they are (in the sense of maven) different artifacts. The groupId is not in any way technically related to the packaging of the classes in the artifact. So for Maven to allow you to have both artifacts you need to change either groupId or artifactId (or both). To avoid class name clashes, you need to rename the packages.

Comment: Ok that's where I am confused, I thought by renaming the groupId/artifiactId you were in fact renaming the packages, but I guess not?

Comment: No, often the groupId is used a first part of the packaging, and the artifactId is also often used there, but this is just convention. Changing the groupId or artifactId does not change package names (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

If you do that, then you must also change the package of your classes; otherwise you will cause even more conflicts to your clients. Looking at the commons-collections jars; the package for version3 is `org\apache\commons\collections\..` and in version 4, they changed the package to `org\apache\commons\collections4\..` .

So that a client can import *both* libraries and use both of them at runtime, and still have no conflicts.

---

So to answer your question, it is *not* enough to change the groupId/artifactId. Either you bump the version (and leave groupId/artifactId unchanged); so that maven/gradle will select eg. version 1, if version 1 and 2 are imported. But if you change the artifactId, you circumvent the conflict resolution mechanism based on version-s; and a client could import both. Then in order to not have conflicts, you **must** change the package name (for all classes included in you jar).

Comment: yeah my prior plan was to keep the groupId the same, change the artifactId from `async1` to `async2` to `async3` for each major version change and the version field would be `1.x.x` and then `2.x.x` and then `3.x.x`, and also in the codebase the directory structure needs to change from  `/src/main/java/com/oresoftware/async1` to  `/src/main/java/com/oresoftware/async2` to  `/src/main/java/com/oresoftware/async3`, and that's it.. AFAICT

Answer (score 0):

Alright so here is the plan

1. Keep the *groupId* the same
2. Change the *artifactId* from `async1` to `async2` to `async3` for each major version change and the version field would be `1.x.x` and then `2.x.x` and then `3.x.x`
3. in the codebase the directory structure needs to change from `src/main/java/com/oresoftware/async1` to `src/main/java/com/oresoftware/async2` to `src/main/java/com/oresoftware/async3`

and that's it.. AFAICT